# Luna template - How do I change my home page to display in 2x2 grid instead of 3x2

Tags: bigcartel

I want to change the layout on our home page to display products in a 2x2 grid which would be static rather than a 3x2 grid as the template is set up for. Can anyone give advise on how to do this?

here is the site:
wamcoshirt.bigcartel.com

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just head to Customize Design > Advanced > CSS in Big Cartel, and add this at the very bottom:

```
#home_page .canvas {
  max-width: 590px;
}
```